# How to sum lines in a QWEB report (Odoo 13)?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I have a report and here is what I want to do. [image: Odoo Report]

This is from the stock-picking batch model.

I was able to add a span line so

```
<span t-esc="move_operation.mapped('picking_id').display_name"/>
```

This gives me the names of the products but I need to be able to add the lines.

I have tried

```
<t t-esc="sum(l.price_total for l in move_operation.mapped('picking_id') " />
```

But haven't had success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is like its done in invoice:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d3a6afe51fc4b864368acbc40a86ac6974d328dd/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml#L72

You initjalize a variable.

`<t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0"/>`
On each row you add values to your variable.

```
 <t t-foreach="lines" t-as="line">
     <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_subtotal"/>
```

and then print it.

`<span t-esc="current_subtotal"/>`